# ¿Por qué "ser agalludo" es ser ambicioso o avariento?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, hispanoamérica

En el DLE se puede encontrar esta entrada:

> [agalludo, da.](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=agalludo)
>
> De *agalla* y -*udo*.
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Arg., Chile, P. Rico y Ur. p. us. Dicho de una persona: Animosa, resuelta, valiente.
> 2. adj. coloq. Col., Ec., R. Dom. y Ur. Ambicioso, avariento.

La primera acepción la relaciono con la expresión "tener agallas", que se encuentra en una de las acepciones para [agalla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=12nt1M0%7C12yWYX9):

> 8. f. pl. coloq. Arrestos, valentía, audacia. *Tener agallas*.

Pero con segunda acepción no encuentro una relación clara entre "agalla" y ser ambicioso o avariento. ¿De dónde viene esta relación?

Comment: La acepción 10 de "agalla" es "codicia, ansia desmedida", usada en Ecuador, México, Puerto Rico, República Dominicana y Venezuela (y en más países [según el _Diccionario de americanismos_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=agalla)). "Agalludo" vendrá de dicha acepción de "agalla", pero esto tan solo traslada tu pregunta: ¿cuál es el origen de "agalla" como "codicia" en estos países?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En [Semántica hispanoamericana](https://books.google.cl/books?id=QGddAAAAMAAJ&q=agallas%20avaro&dq=agallas%20avaro&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI19q8g7DYAhVKGJAKHVVgCZ8Q6AEIMjAC) de Charles Emil Kany se plantea esta interesante teoría:

> *agalla* (de pez) por 'codicia', ya que el rápido abrirse y cerrarse de las agallas sugiere avaricia, deriv. *agalludo* 'codicioso, avaro'.